# How to run a kubernetes pod as NFS server?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nfs

I have the following problem:

- We have an S3 Minio Storage with a dataset consisting of ~600k files which amount to around 1.3Tb of storage space
- On our Kubernetes cluster I want to run a training using the dataset multiple times. I however want to avoid downloading the data multiple times from the S3 Server to save times and also not overload it with requests
- My solution would be a PVC, where I first load all the data and then mount it into the training pods. However, here is the problem: according to my sysadmin the storage reserved for PVCs currently has only around 200Gbs free space available.
- Our cluster is currently in the process of being rebuild (so that we can mount data directly into pods in the future for example :D ), but for I need a workaround. This brought up the idea of simply using a separate pod to download and store all of the data and then share it with the training pods by usage of an nfs server.
- Mounting a NFS volume is described here in the [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs) documentation, this seems to be straight forward.
- However, I am a real noob when it comes to file systems, networking and linux as a whole. I tried to go with [this Ubuntu tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-nfs), but get stuck at the missing `systemctl` command. I have also tried to look for "ready-to-go" nfs-server docker images but have not really found a good one with docs on how to set it up in a kubernetes cluster.

So basically I am looking for a starting point, where I can simply run a pod with python, run a script to download all my data locally and then share it to other pods. Not sure, how to get started.

Comment: I'm very confused: if you system only has 200GB of free space for PVs, where would your hypothetical nfs server pod get its storage? It seems like you've just moved the problem into another place. If you need a userspace NFS server, that typically means you want the [nfs-ganesha](https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha) project, but I'm not sure that this nfs server idea makes sense to begin with.

Comment: Honestly the k8s cluster has a few problems and is currently completely re-planned and will get a new setup. But this will take a few months - so for the time being, I need a workaround. Basically (at least as far as I understand - I'm not a sysadmin, only a programmer who is supposed to use the cluster) storage for PVCs is a separate reserved storage. On the other hand ephemeral storage local to pods is quite big (several TBs) so that is why I want to load everything locally into one pod and make it an nfs-server for other pods. I hope this makes somewhat sense....